# Drive Realtime API not granting permission to realtime document; normal drive API freaking out

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

My app uses the Drive rest API and the Drive Realtime API in combination. We set the file's permissions so that the public has view access, and then emailed a link to it to a few thousand customers.

The file's permissions are set so that the public has view access, but:

1. When a user tries to open the realtime document, we get `Drive Realtime API Error: not_found: File not found.`
2. When a user tries to copy the non-realtime file, we get `The authenticated user has not granted the app 689742286244 write access to the file 0B-NHh5QARZiUUFctN0Zjc3RKdWs` (of course we are not asking to write

You can see the effects for yourself at https://peardeck.com/editor/0B-NHh5QARZiUUFctN0Zjc3RKdWs , and our embarrassing attempts to cover for the errors.

Interesting notes:

- Sharing the file directly with a particular google account seems to lift the curse, and then that google account can find the file like normal. No extra permissions, just an explicit reference to a google account.
- Setting the file so that the public has full write access seems to have no effect
- Other files with the exact same settings in the exact same Drive folder can be opened successfully (but presumably have not been opened by so many people in the past). This makes me think there is some broken state within Google.

How can I avoid this? What's going on?(!?!?) Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realtime API does not support anonymous access.  All users must have a Google account and be explicitly authorized to view or write to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. All of my users *are* logged in with a Google account. Sometimes people can access files that aren't explicitly shared with them, and the `isAnonymous` flag is properly set as in https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Collaborator ... so it was a surprise when it stopped working. I'm sorry I missed this point - we were really looking forward to sharing our documents publicly.

Comment: For example, https://peardeck.com/editor/0B0pmf7u-VSmjd1FuejNHNi1fYUE will take you to a file to which you don't have explicit access, but which (for now) will work just fine once you log in